# How to solve lost connection problem in Couchbase UI

Tags: kubernetes, couchbase, amazon-eks

We've 4 shared nodes for data, index, query, search, analytics, eventing and 1 shared node for query and index. After a few minutes logged in the ui we are facing "lost connection to server" problem even though nodes are running and healthy.

- couchbase operator version -> v2.1.0
- couchbase version -> v6.6.0
- node type -> m5.xlarge

I logged in couchbase ui but could not get any action because of lost connection error.

Comment: I see operator and node type, so I'm assuming you're deploying to Kubernetes. Is it AKS?

Comment: Hey, yes I'm deploying to Kubernetes and it is EKS.